# MikTeX Update corrupts the installation

Tags: miktex

I tried to Update MikTex as I have done before, with the Update (admin) console. I get a window with a few items checked and grayed out "Select All" and "Select None" buttons. I clicked on Next and the update does something. 
MikTex cannot start - I get an error message about a missing module, etc.

I uninstalled it (it did not go smoothly) and installed it again. It worked but it could not automatically install a package on one computer; and worked well on another. The updater still behaves the same way.

This is on two different machines, both running Win 8.1.

Comment: Install first the new packages and then run updates. See my comment here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257643/latex-exe-system-error-qtgui4-dll-missing-from-your-computer#comment617560_257643. And next time put more effort in your problem description. The names of the "missing module" is important.

Comment: When there are MikTeX specific updates next to the regular package updates, MikTeX first wants to update itself before updating anything else.

Comment: I synchronized the list but I do not understand this: " Then check in the package list if there are new packages starting with miktex and install them." How do I know which are new and start with miktex?   Also, to give you the name of the missing module, I have to go over the whole thing again, and I would like no to do that.          BTW, the "Select All" button is still grayed out. Should I try to see what happens?

Comment: Can't you just run the update with the selected packages at first and then  run another update where you (hopefully) can select all the packages you like?

Comment: I did just that. It seemed to work. But then I could not print. I have seen that before when I had problems. Click on Print - nothing happens. Then I reinstalled the whole thing, no updates. Print works now. I will just leave it like that.

Comment: Mhhh, what "print" button are you talking about and what does it have to do with MikTeX and its updater?

Comment: "Print PDF" (not really a button) in the PDF viewer. It does not work after the update.